# Prove that the open first quadrant in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

Let $Q$ be the “open first quadrant” in $\mathbb{R}^d,$ i.e., $Q=\{x= (x_1, . . . , x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d:x_1, . . . , x_d>0\}.$ Prove that $Q$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d.$

A set is open if for every $x \in Q,$ there is an $r>0$ such that $B_r(x) \in Q.$ To start the proof, I think that I should let some variable, say $y$, be $y \in B_r(x),$ and try to show that $y \in Q.$ So by definition of an open ball of radius $r,$ with $r>0$, we have $|x-y|<r$. I am not sure how to use this to get to $y\in Q$ though. Is this the right path ?

Comment: I would suggest you draw a picture in two dimensions first. Given an $x\in Q$, can you first find a small square $S$ (in 2-dimensions, or in n-dimensions a cube) centered at $x$ such that $S\subset Q$? Now, can you see how to fit a ball inside such a square (cube)?

Answer (score 1):

(To use this proof, you must apply some theory.) Let $S_k$ be the inverse image of $(0,\infty)$ by the $k$-th projection. (Projections are continuous.)
$$Q=S_1\cap...\cap S_k$$